# Microsoft-metro style grid, build dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, microsoft-metro, calculated-columns

I want to make some sort of jQuery plugin that can fill a 3 X 3 grid (like microsoft-metro style). It should be something like this:

- If I have 1 tile, it should take the whole grid (1-9).
- If I have 2 tiles, it should be one tile (1-6) and another tile (7-9).
- If I have 3 tiles, it should take (1-2 and 4-5), (3 and 6), (7-9)
- If I have 5 tiles, it should take (1-2), (3), (4-6), (7), (8-9)

And so on!

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
-------------
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
-------------
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
-------------
```

Is it possible to dynamically fill my grid based on the number of tiles (with a maximum of 9). Is there some sort of calculation for it?

Comment: Maybe JQuery Isotope: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/.  That's used by the StackExchanges sites page: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: -ms-flex`, with `-ms-flex-Wrap: wrap`. This will let you wrap automatically. You'll need to size your items per the number you want.

Another option is to use `-ms-grid`, and configure the column/rows (and spans) based on the items.